# How to show the convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $\{A_k, k=0,1,\ldots\}$ be a sequence of complex square matrices such that $A_k - A_{k-1} = C^k$ where spectral radius of $C$ is less than 1. I want to show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} A_k$ exists. Is the following approach correct?

*If we define $B_k = A_k - A_{k-1}$, then, we know $\lim_{k \to \infty} B_k =0$. Therefore, $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_k$ exists.*

Comment: No, that alone isn't sufficient.  For example the sequence 1, 1+ 1/2= 3/2, 3/2+ 1/3= 11/6, 11/6+ 1/4= 25/12, etc. where $f_n= f_{n-1}+ 1/n$ has the property that $f_n- f_{n-1}= 1/n$ which  goes to 0 but this sequence is the sequence of partial sums of the *harmonic series*  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ which does NOT converge.  Instead you need show that this is a geometric series.  Since $a_n- a_{n-1]=  c^k$, $f_1= f_0+ c$ $f_2= f_1+ c^2= f_0+ c+ c^2$, $f_3= f_2+ c^3= f_0+ c+ c^2+ c^3$, etc.

Comment: @user247327 Thanks for the counterexample for the general $f$. But, for the specific one I have, that approach is correct?

Comment: As a mathematician (or at least as someone studying mathematics), you must know that that "Therefore" requires **proof** ...

Comment: Wow, that is **a huge** change wrt the original question! How in the freaking world did you pass from sequences of numbers and functions to... **matrices*?

Comment: @DonAntonio the proof below adapts readily though.

Comment: @GabrielRomon No, not really "readily". A first undergraduate can understand a proof about sequences, limits and etc. Something related to matrices, topolgy on matrices, spectral radius and etc. requires much more than the basics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
As others have stated,
the standard example is
$a_k
=\sum_{j=1}^k \frac1{j}
$
where
$a_k-a_{k-1}
=\frac1{k}
\to 0$
but
$a_k \to \infty$.

However,
if
$a_k-a_{k-1} = c^k$,
then,
summing from
$1$ to $n$,
$\sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-a_{k-1}) = \sum_{k=1}^nc^k$,
or
$a_n-a_0
=\dfrac{c-c^{n+1}}{1-c}
=\dfrac{c}{1-c}-\dfrac{c^{n+1}}{1-c}
$
so,
since
$c^{n+1} \to 0$,
$a_n
\to a_0+\dfrac{c}{1-c}
$.